# Recommended git mode for Emacs

Tags: git, emacs23

As a recent convert to git and a long-time Emacs hacker I'm wondering what other serious Emacs/Git hackers recommend for git support in Emacs23.  I've already started using the VC git backend and find it somewhat of a thin abstraction layer of git's capabilities.  So I'm inclined to try another.  Googling turns up a half dozen or so choices in addition to the standard Emacs VC support.

If you prefer magit or egg, why?  And if your recommendation has platform dependencies, how so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I started out using git.el (which comes with Git). The main reason was because I had been used to [psvn.el](http://www.xsteve.at/prg/emacs/psvn.el) to work with Subversion and I was looking for something similar for Git. And since git.el has compatible key bindings, it was my first stop.

However, I was really starting to enjoy staging my commits (and not staging the complete file, but only chunks) and git.el did not support this properly. To make a long story short: I'm using [Magit](http://zagadka.vm.bytemark.co.uk/magit/) at the moment and I'm loving it.

To be honest, I haven't used Magit yet to do e.g. rebasing or merging. I'm still using the command line for that. But my opinion, Magit has a better mapping of the functionality Git has to offer.

Comment: I have started using Magit and find it quite satisfying due to the closer match to git.  Good enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

I use Magit mode.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I can't comment on egg, but I have been using git + emacs steadily for 12 months. I tried git, git gui, vc-git, git.el, and magit. I read all about other stuff. I settled in using the git command line to commission new repos, clone, and other infrequent configurational stuff. I do most git operations (say 97%) via magit.  And... I'm a happy camper ;)